# Control may reach end of non-void function C

Tags: c, function, void

I am not able to compile my code, I am getting error: control may reach the end of a non-void function

```
/**
 * Returns true if value is in array of n values, else false.
 */
bool search(int value, int values[], int n)
{
    //Binary search algorithm
    int first = 0;
    int last = n-1;
    int middle = (first+last)/2;

    if (n<1)
        return false;
    else
    {
        while (first <= last)
        {
            if (values[middle]==value)
                return true;
            else if(values[middle]<value)
                first=middle+1;
            else if (values[middle]>value)
            {
                last=middle-1; 
            }
            middle=(first+last)/2;
        }
    }

    if (first>last)
        return false;
}
```

Can anyone look through my code and help me figure out where the issue is? I am struggling to see it myself! From my point of view, this function returns true or false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code it's not possible for the function to fall off the end.

However, the compiler is not required to accurately diagnose whether a function can get to the end or not. In general, to do so would require solving the halting problem.

Instead, as a practical measure, your compiler is doing some basic checks and warning because it sees the `if ( first > last ) return false;`, it didn't do enough code analysis to determine that this branch can never be reached unless `first > last`.

To suppress this warning you could just remove the line `if ( first > last )`.  BTW this is a warning, not an error; so it should not prevent your compilation.

Comment: Thanks, this indeed solved the problem! If its true it will never get there and the code will exit, therefore if it exist the while-loop I should just return false meaning the number couldnt be found!

Answer (score 2):

Your return type of `bool` means that your function is always expected to return a boolean value before it exits, no matter which path of execution it takes. As it stands now, it *appears* on inspection that you can "fall through" the last `if` and never hit a return statement. To verify otherwise would require stepping through your logic in a way the compiler cannot reasonably be expected to do. At the end simply change to say:

```
  if (first>last) {
      return false;
  } else {
      return true;
  }
```

Or more concisely:

```
 return (first > last) ? false : true;
```

Comment: `return (first <= last);`

Comment: @PhilPerry that's even more concise. I guess I was going for minimal edit to his existing code so didn't want to use the inverse of his test, but I prefer your way. Also, I should point out that it may be impossible for the code to *actually* reach the end of the function but there is no way for the compiler to *know* that by inspection in reasonable time, so you need the `else` or equivalent to make it happy.

Comment: unless I'm seriously missing something there is not a path that falls through to the final `}` without hitting a `return` (except for paths that have already caused UB)

Comment: See my comment above, the compiler can only do superficial checking, it can't (in reasonable time) actually test the logic under a range of inputs to verify that.

Comment: Yeah, it may or may not be clearer to someone reading the code. I doubt it has much effect on the efficiency of the compiled code, for most compilers. As others have pointed out, it's apparently not possible to fall off the end, so the test can be eliminated and a fixed **true** or **false** returned. The author would probably want to comment that, to make it clear that flow can't get to that point without certain conditions being true.